# Empties not fully processing in node tree

Tags: animation-nodes

I'm not sure if this is a limitation of the way I'm using animation nodes or of this is an actual bug.  I have a file that I am reading to instantiate a list of empties to use as falloff object controllers.  When the frame comes that creates the empties, only one is initially processed and I have to execute the node tree again to have the rest of the empties produce their falloff effect.

Does this require me to have execute always on to have all of the empties fill in their falloff information or is there something about the order in which I'm doing things.  In that regard - is there another way for me to use the distance away from an object to determine if nearby objects should be scaled that will update properly?

[image: Entering frame where empties are created]

Right now the project I am working on is just a static viewer resulting from a file while I'm learning what I can do with animation nodes. I preferably wouldn't want to use always execute for a static viewer that should only need to update once per frame.

[image]

Example from image.

[image: Adding Image for reference]
Probably not relevant to the question, but for reference this is the node tree.

Comment: I noticed some parts of animation nodes not working in 2.8. If you can recreate the problem in a minified, simplified file, you should file a [bug report](https://github.com/JacquesLucke/animation_nodes/issues).

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround.  I just needed to put in an execution trigger that moved an object based on the frame. It's a little hacky but it gets the desired result.